# Why is this recursive solution faster than the iterative solution?

Tags: python, recursion, optimization, iteration

I wrote a recursive solution for something today, and as it goes, curiosity led me down a weird path. I wanted to see how an optimized recursive solution compares to an iterative solution so I chose a classic, the Nth Fibonacci to test with.

I was surprised to find that the recursive solution with memoization is much faster than the iterative solution and I would like to know why.

Here is the code (using python3):

```py
import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

## recursive:
def fibr(n, memo = {}):
    if n <= 1:
        return n

    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]

    memo[n] = fibr(n-1, memo) + fibr(n-2, memo)

    return memo[n]

## iterative:
def fibi(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

rstart = time.time()
for n in range(10000):
    fibr(n)
rend = time.time()

istart = time.time()
for n in range(10000):
    fibi(n)
iend = time.time()

print(f"recursive: {rend-rstart}")
print(f"iterative: {iend-istart}")
```

My results:

```
recursive: 0.010010004043579102
iterative: 6.274333238601685
```

Unless I'm mistaken, both the recursive solution and the iterative solution are about as optimized as they can get?  If I'm wrong about that, I'd like to know why.

If not, what would cause the iterative solution to be so much slower?  It seems to be slower for all values of `n`, but harder to notice when `n` is something more reasonable, like `<1000`. (I'm using `10000` as you can see above)

**Some things I've tried:**

1. I thought it might be the magic swapping in the iterative solution `a, b = b, a + b`, so I tried replacing it with a more traditional "swap" pattern:

```py
tmp = a + b     
a = b           
b = tmp         
#a, b = b, a + b
```

But the results are basically the same, so that's not the problem there.

2. Re-arrange the code so that the iterative solution runs first, just to see if there was some weird cache issue at the OS level? It doesn't change the results so that's not it, probably?

My understanding here (and it might be wrong) is that the recursive solution with memoization is `O(n)`. And the iterative solution is also `O(n)` simply because it iterates from `0..n`.

Am I missing something really obvious?  I feel like I must be missing something here.

Comment: `def fibr(n, memo = {}):` probably [doesn't do what you expect it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: @GManNickG is this relevant to my question though? I'm wondering why the recursive solution is faster than the iterative one

Comment: It is _the_ reason it is faster. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might expect that `def fibr(n, memo = {}):` — when called without a supplied `memo` — turns into something translated a bit like:

```
def _fibr_without_defaults(n, memo):
   ...

def fibr(n):
    return _fibr_without_defaults(n, {})
```

That is, if `memo` is missing it implicitly gets a blank dictionary per your default.

[In actuality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), it translates into something more like:

```
def _fibr_without_defaults(n, memo):
   ...

_fibr_memo_default = {}
def fibr(n):
    return _fibr_without_defaults(n, _fibr_memo_default)
```

That is, a default argument value is not "use this to construct a default value" but instead "use *this actual value* by default". Every single call to `fibr` you make (without supplying `memo`) is *sharing* a default `memo` dictionary.

---

That means in:

```
for n in range(10000):
    fibr(n)
```

The prior iterations of your loop are filling out `memo` for the future iterations. When `n` is 1000, for example, all the work performed by `n<=999` is still stored.

By contrast, the iterative version always starts iterating from 0, no matter what work prior iterative calls performed.

---

If you perform the translation above by hand, so that you really do get a fresh empty `memo` for each call, you'll see the iterative version is faster. (Makes sense; inserting things into a dictionary and retrieving them just to do the same work as simple iteration will be slower.)

Comment: I guess a proper way to test it is to call `fibr(n, {})` initially. And a proper way to define is to not use `memo = {}` in the definition. Since memoization is caching and there is no real "expiration" of this cache with a default parameter value, that leads to a memory leak. The severity might depend on the function but adding more and more results to a *global* cache means it will grow indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. When passing `{}` when calling the the function in the loop (and increasing the recursion limit to 10001), the results are quite different:

recursive: 46.7815842628479
iterative: 7.397951126098633

Comment: @Kevin seems plausible. Obviously, the numbers might vary depending on the system but a factor of 6-7 is more in line with what the difference could be.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

The recursive version uses the [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) pattern, calculating only once the result of `fibr(n)` and storing/caching the result for insta-return if needed again. It's an O(n) algorithm.

The iterative version calculates everything from scratch. It's an O(n2) algorithm (I think).

Comment: Why do you say that the recursive solution is `O(n log n)`?  My understanding is that it's actually `O(2n)`, which is simplified to `O(n)`. I imagine the recursive solution as a really tall tree from `n`, down to `0` where each left node has 2 children, and everything is cached

Comment: @Kevin I initially guessed O(n), but I edited it to O(n log n). I’ve restored O(n).

Comment: :) no worries.  I've been thinking about this for the last few hours and I still can't understand why the recursive solution is faster. Can you explain why the iterative solution is so much slower?